# How to check if a stripe account is verified

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Is there a way in php to check if a standalone account connected to your stripe application is verified?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With standalone accounts you'd check `details_submitted` on the [Account object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object). If it's `true` it means the account has been activated while if it's `false` it means it's been created but not activated yet.

Unless you use [Deferred](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/deferred-accounts) accounts though an account can't be connected to your Production platform without being activated already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! to be activeted, the user must fill details and submit document? or is enough fill the form of details? because we need to check legal_identity but I saw it is only for managed account.

Comment: @MarcoMirabile: The user needs to activate their Stripe account the same way you activated yours by filling out details about their business and their bank account details and their identity. Once they do this you'll see `details_submitted: true` and `charges_enabled: true` and `transfers_enabled: true`

Comment: Thanks!! Very usefull info!

Comment: These attributes Will be true when user upload his documentation to stripe? Because testing in development mode they became true just filling the details form (with random info)...

Answer (score 1):

Those three fields tells you if an account is valid and active and not that is verified, but what if you need to check if user has uploaded an id document to verify his identity? 
If your business requires that kind of information but you don't have resources to manage accounts and you want to use standalone accounts what could you do?
Verification of users (to check they are what they say there are) could  be very important for particular type of service.

Thanks